# An explanation of the Zend Redirector Action Helper

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

Is there a comprehensive explanation of how the Zend Redirector Action Helper works?  I've read the reference guide, but am still not 100% clear.  For example:

- Apparently the goToSimple() is more like a forward(), than a redirect.  Does this mean that it won't send a redirect message back to the browser?
- If I want to send a redirect message back to the browser, which Redirector method should I be using?
- Is there a way to get the forward() type of behaviour, without re-executing the init() method of Action Helpers?

This problem cropped up when I was implementing an ACL.  I have an ACL Action Helper and its init() method adds the role 'current'.  When I use the redirector's goToSimple() I get an error saying that the role is already registered.  I can use `if (!$acl->hasRole('current'))` however I think it would be preferable not to be re-executing the helper's init() in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Not too comprehensive just a few quick notes about the redirector.

The redirector does a little bit more than a regular PHP redirect which you would use with `header('Location: www.domain.com/new/location')` in your script--following by an `exit()`.

If you look at **Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector** it ultimately does exactly the same; if $_exit==true (default) everything leads to `redirectAndExit()` which calls `header()` and ends with an `exit()` call. However it terminates the framework properly, mainly the session if any.

The redirector does not forward internally it sends a default 302 code back unless you have set another code with `setCode()`.

Methods `gotoRoute()` and `gotoSimple()` assemble the destination URL for you and call `redirectAndExit()` but only if `$_exit==true`. Or you can use their brethren `gotoRouteAndExit()` and `gotoSimpleAndExit()` which will exit immediately. The gotoSimple methods pass on to setGotoSimple which uses some methods to assemble the URL for you.

In your case I can only assume that the `setGotoSimple` method and one of the methods in it call the destination controller and fire up the init() method; however, only for checking but not forwarding.